# React - Can .reduce() be updated like useState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a little project and I am currently working on the "Cart". The only part missing on the cart currently, is getting the total price of each product.

I've managed to do that, but if for instance you want 2 of a product. It does not update.

The products in the cart is inside of a context, and the price updates there whenever you increase, or decrease the amount of each product.

But the part where I display "total price" does not update. I have tried to use a `useState()` for this part, but with no success. I read a bit about `useReducer()`, but not really sure how it works. Is it exactly the same as JavaScript's `.reduce()`?

Here is the part of the code where this needs to be calculated:

```
  // Add to cart context
  const { cartItems } = useContext(AddToCartContext);

  // Filtering double products
  let cart = cartItems.filter(
    (ele, ind) => ind === cartItems.findIndex((elem) => elem.id === ele.id && elem.size === ele.size)
  );

  // This adds all product prices together, displays a total price
  let totalPrice = cart.reduce(
    (totalPrice, item) => totalPrice + item.price,
    0
  )
  // Though, it does not update "live" like a useState.
```

Also, here is a picture of the object (how it looks like), might be useful:
[image]

Thanks!

Edit: Code for Context

AddToCartContext:

```
import React from "react";

const AddToCartContext = React.createContext([]);

export default AddToCartContext;
```

Code for AddToCartContext onClick:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() =>
    setCartItems((cartItems) => [
      ...cartItems,
      {
        name: props.name,
        price: props.price,
        color: props.mainImg?.colour,
        img: props.mainImg?.url,
        id: params.productid,
        size: selectedSize,
        count: 1,
      },
    ])
  }
  className={classes.add_to_cart}
>
  <Cart />
  add to cart
</button>
```

Comment: `Is it exactly the same as JavaScript's reduce` - no. They're very different.

Comment: Oh okay, so `useReducer()` cannot be a replacement for the `.reduce()` in my scenario?

Comment: `reduce` is an array method. `useReducer` is a react state API method https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer they may look similar, but they're not interchangeable.

Comment: correct, `useReducer()` is for complex state management, not for reducing an array. In order to get the "live update", you need to force a re-render whenever an item get's added. How does an item get added currently?

Comment: An item get added to the cart upon a button press ("Add To Cart"). The products are being added and there is checks to make sure duplicates does not get added etc, works perfectly. But the issue I am having is that my "TOTAL: " does not update, "live". @JoeLissner

Comment: can you add the code for your context ?

Comment: Have been added @Shyam

Comment: Can you show us your provider as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useReducer` is the API provided by React to mimic the behaviour of Redux/Flux's pattern for updating state

view layer  -> dispatch an action -> a reducer function to update your state based on your action

It is not related to the `reduce` of JavaScript.